# Install HDF (Hierarchical Data Format) and P3DFFT

Tags: software-installation

How do I install HDF(Hierarchical Data Format) and P3DFFT in ubuntu?

Comment: Hello to AU.  Please review [how to ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Quote: _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!_

Comment: You don't *install* a data format. You install software that *use* or *understand* a certain data-format.

Answer (score 1):

HDF-related packages are presented in the [official Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=hdf).

In order to install these you'll likely need to [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) first with
`sudo add-apt-repository universe`.

About P3DFFT you should read its documentation on [official web-site](https://www.p3dfft.net/install-p3dfft).